# Iwant to learn programming but i dont know where to start from

Tags: programming

I'm really into hacking and security aspects. But I'm wondering about several things that is stopping me from pursuing this passion for the time being. One of the them is actually Programming language. As we all know that programming in general is an open-ended field, and what I mean you can't just by learning the basics of a language go into writing complex programs or exploitation

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is off-topic here. It is also very open-ended and up to a lot of opinion.

Answer (score 2):

About your question:

1. This is an Information Security related website, so it is not the best place to learn about programming.
2. If you want to learn about programming I recommend you to start learning Python Programming Language, it's pretty easy to learn and very powerful, also is available in every platform (Windows, GNU Linux, Mac OS X).
3. After learning python, I recommend you to learn Ruby, a lot of exploits from Metasploit are created in ruby, you can check the source code if you want: [Metasploit Source Code on Github](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework)

Hope it helps, good luck and for future programming questions, please use [Stack Overflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com/) instead.

Comment: please do not answer clearly off-topic questions but flag for migration and answer there

Comment: Oh, Ok, got it.

Comment: The question is clearly bogus but I still like the answer (esp. Ruby aspect).